# Checking a String if it Contains Letters

Tags: java, string, list

I have a question on how to do something involving strings and lists in java. I want to be able to enter a string say for example

> "aaa"

using the scanner class and the program must return the shortest word with three a's in it. So for example there is a text file filled with thousands of words that is to be checked with the input and if it has three a's in it, then it is a candidate but now it has be the shortest to return only that one. How exactly do you go about comparing and seeing if an input of letters is in all the words of a text file filled with words?

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a vist to the [`java.lang.String` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

In particular, take a look at [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).  I'll forgive you for missing this one because of the parameter requirements.

Example:

```
String text = //...
if (text.contains("aaa")) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can work with that. My only other question is, would I write this in the main method or a separate method included with finding the shortest string to return. Basically I have to run through every word in the file of words and find the shortest string with that input "aaa" or any set of letters.

Comment: Personally, I write two methods, one for the longest and one for the shortest, but you'll need to make that decision yourself based on your overall needs, that's just my opinion on the info I have available ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
          while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(input.contains(find)) // first find the the value contains in the whole line. 
                {
                   String[] splittedValues = input.split(" "); // if the line contains the given word split it all to extract the exact word.
                   for(String values : splittedValues)
                   {
                       if(values.contains(find))
                       {
                           System.out.println("all words : "+values);
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use `String.contains()` and a loop that checks length:

```
String search = "aaa"; // read user input
String fileAsString; // read in file
String shortest = null;
for (String word : fileAsString.split("\\s*")) {
    if (word.contains(search) && (shortest == null || word.length() < shortest.length())) {
        shortest = word;
    }
}
// shortest is either the target or null if no matches found.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but my only other question is, would I write this in the main method or a separate method included with finding the shortest string to return. Basically I have to run through every word in the file of words and find the shortest string with that input "aaa" or any set of letters

Comment: If you do it separately, you would have to store all the words, which is unnecessary. I suppose you could first get all words with the letter sequence, then call another method to find the shortest. If you did that, I would sort the list on length using a Conparator then get the zeroth element if the list